# Azure b2c custom policy login redirect through Azure front door is defaulting 404 to a domain I am unsure of how to manage. How do I redirect the 404

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-front-door

I have a domain that is protected through Azure b2c. The way I set it up is that a domain linked through Azure front-door is the login domain.

`login.contoso.com`

The app domain is

`my.contoso.com`

What is happening is that when I go to `login.contoso.com` (without any routing or path redirect uri's) directly it will default to a `404 error` and land on this page

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

To note, the correct path works. i.e. `login.contoso.com/<token>azureb2c...`

The issue is how to I handle the `404 error?`

I'd like to default direct that to my main domain site i.e. `contoso.com` or `someotherpage`.

The odd part for me is that because the domain, sub-domain, is `login.contoso.com` I don't think there is actually a page from Azure emitting that. I think, correctly, that is just my domain's way of handling 404's or wrong page.

I already handle the redirect if the person goes to `my.contoso.com` and isn't logged in they go directly to `login.contoso.com` However, I don't think i'm handling the `404 errors` correctly because anything outside of that emits the previously described error screen.

So I think the question is, how can I direct a subdomain's 404 to a url of my choosing of a domain that is setup through Azure front-door?

Is that just in the same permissions of my webconfig for the main app service domain ie., `contoso.com`? Or, is it the webconfig of the app service specifically for the subdomain `my.contoso.com`?

Comment: At front door, you could always create a custom routing rule to redirect to the default page.

Comment: hi @Thomas that is not working because the routing doesn't handle the error something else is redirecting the error.

Comment: What path is this? login.contoso.com/<token>azureb2c... What fires the redirect to login.contoso.com? In what scenarios will you land into login.contoso.com without any without any routing or path redirect uri's? Which are those?

Comment: hi @AlfredoRevilla-MSFT thanks. The path of <token>azureb2c that works correctly. The redirect works correctly as that is managed in the client. The last question is if the person logs out or try's to land on the page directly i.e. login.contoso.com or they try to refresh a link and they're session is timed out they should (well maybe in that scenario they just re-login probably). But mostly, it is from trying to hit the subdomain directly we want them to land back to our advertisement page.

Comment: Hi @ChristianMatthew, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely **configure the redirection for your different subdomains from a particular subdomain URL while logging in or any other kind of activity like session auto-logout after token expiration by configuring the correct routing rules for redirection in the Azure front door classic version**.

Kindly check the snapshot below as demonstrated according to your requirement: -

[image: Front door routing rule - 1]
[image: Front door routing rule - 2]

Thus, according to the above snapshots, you can **configure the redirection for the ‘login.contoso.com’ URL to the desired domain URL of your choice, i.e., ‘contoso.com’ or ‘someotherpage.com’ for in Azure AD B2C too**.

•   Also, in the above snapshot, I have selected **‘Temporary Redirect (307)’** for HTTPS protocol as according to the below documentation link, `the target resource is temporarily under a different URI. The user agent MUST NOT change the request method if it does an automatic redirection to that URI. Since the redirection can change over time, the client ought to continue using the original effective request URI for future requests`.

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-redirect?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#redirection-types*

As you want the redirection to happen for the ‘login.contoso.com’ URL when you redirect to that page, it will surely happen when you configure it accordingly as above since **this redirection is temporary according to the situations stated above.**

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering what i am saying. but let me key on this phrase you posted here. "The user agent MUST NOT change the request method if it does an automatic redirection to that URI." Are you saying that the user must not alter the login domain? Meaning, that if they go directly to login.contoso.com it should expect to error our to a generic server page? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: If you go here to this URL https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/ this server page is what I am trying to route. I don't want to land people to a generic server page. It makes no sense. It seems like a security risk as well.

Comment: Yes, since you want to redirect/route the incoming traffic requests of 404 error page to a custom defined page in your application everytime it encounters this error, the above should help you in defining the same. And it doesn't mean that everytime the user tries to access the 'login.contoso.com' page, it should get redirected to the custom defined page because you would be mentioning the 404 error page in the destination host to be replaced.

Comment: And only then, when the Azure front door route detects the 404 URL error, the custom path/page in the application will be redirected to and the path to be mentioned in the destination path doesn't necessarily mean a generic page but any image or custom HTML page designed when encountering this error.

Comment: Hi, is the 2nd screen shot a redirect rule?

Comment: Yes, both the screenshots are of the same page regarding creating a redirect routing rule in Azure CDN.

Comment: ok can you explain what the rule is doing. are you saying it is an exact match that www.contoso.com would go to /posts/requests <<< Is that correct? however, if login.contoso.com would go where? I'm trying to understand what it is we're doing here.

Comment: We are just trying to redirect requests that are received for the 404 error page to the website main page, i.e., www.contoso.com, nothing else. This would ensure that whenever the user would be encountering 404 error page, anywhere during the B2C custom policy user flow, it would be redirected directly to the the main website page rather than displaying the error page. Its simple like that. In this way, you can configure the redirect to a URL of your choosing for the 404 error page.